# Vim-CtrlP Is it possible to set ctrlp_cache_dir to project root?

Tags: vim

In the docs there is this example:

```
Set the directory to store the cache files:
  let g:ctrlp_cache_dir = $HOME.'/.cache/ctrlp'
```

but part of the plugin's power is that it can detect a .git folder in the parent directory tree, and I imagine keeping the cache there would be most efficient for my standard situation. So before I engaged in attempting an amateur vim script, I wanted to ask if there's a simple way of interpolating something like this:

```
let g:ctrlp_cache_dir = '$GIT_PROJECT/.ctrlp_cache'
```

?

Comment: Why don't you [ask to the author](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/issues) himself?

Comment: @romainl It's a popular enough plugin, so it seemed like a good idea to ask here, but looking into current issues from this angle I might just take your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the author on the project's github, and it turns out to be fairly difficult. Fortunately refreshing the cache with `<F5>` only refreshes the current project directory, so if performance is your goal, as was mine, then this would be a pointless undertaking.

https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/issues/416

Comment: by `refreshing the cache with <F5> only refreshes the current project directory`, do you mean that the files in the current project are readded/refreshed in the cache?

Comment: I don’t know what it does under the hood, but it acts as if the cache is deleted and rebuilt from the actual project directory contents.